# SQLException in JDBC

Tags: optimization, jdbc, informix, sqlexception

I am getting a SQLException when I try to run the query in Informix DB using JDBC.  The query is huge in size:

```
select * table_name where tableid in (....)
```

I get an exception because the 'in' part contain more than 5000 values and because of the length.  Is there a way to avoid this or should I break it down and run two queries?

Answer (score 2):

Create another table with the >5000 `tableid`s.

Then all that's left is an inner-join:

```
select t.* 
  from table_name t 
       inner join table_tableid tid
       on tid.tableid = t.tableid
```